# Accessing private members

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have a class:

```
class A
{
private:
ComplexClass member1;

public:
getMember1(){return member1;};
};
```

and I have an implementation that, for code simplification (more easily understandable), needs to retrieve that member1 to work with it. The first thing that would come to my mind would be:

```
ComplexClass *myComplexClass = &getMember1();

myComplexClass.getSomething();
myComplexClass.getSomethingElse();
etc.
```

which is obviously not correct since I'm retrieving a pointer from a new object and not from member1 (and gets a compiler warning).

My question is: what is the best design to do things like this? How do I keep encapsulation and yet facilitate the access of a members using a pointer to it? (I only want to read from member1, not to write on it).

Should I make a

```
ComplexClass *getPointerToMember1()
```

inside the class A?

Comment: What's wrong with `ComplexClass myComplexClass = a.getMember1(); myComplexClass.getSomething();`?

Comment: You probably should not be adding a getter to start with. Why does the external entity need accesses to member 1. Is this the only entity? If so make it a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A const reference will keep them from editing.  In my opinion, it makes your intention clearer than a const pointer.

```
class A
{
private:
ComplexClass member1;

public:
const ComplexClass &getMember1(){return member1;};
};
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this potentially makes encapsulation trickier, as it means that you *need* a `ComplexClass` object to refer to.  (Imagine a future implementation of `A` that doesn't maintain a member variable, but dynamically creates a `ComplexClass` object on demand.)

Comment: Ok. but I believe that: ComplexClass myComplexClass = A.getMember1(); myComplexClass.someInteger = 10; is a valid implementation.

Comment: @Oli Given the example, we already have an object created.  The way it was phrased, I assume the code is already coupled a little too highly anyway.  I could see this being useful for an odd unit test though.

Comment: @J. C. Leitão You are making a copy with that, it would be valid.  It would not edit the version stored in `A`, which meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the member by value which makes a *copy* of the `ComplexClass` member. Thus you aren't working on the actual member when you call the subsequent methods (and what the compiler is telling you).

I think the more idiomatic C++ approach that helps maintain encapsulation and reduces coupling is to create an algorithmic member:

```
A::doStuff()
{
    member1.getSomething();
    member1.getSomethignElse();
}
```

This way anyone that uses `class A` doesn't *care* that the implementation uses a `ComplexClass` but instead just knows that they can tell `A` to do some work and it will get done in the best possible way.

EDIT for comment: In that case, I would suggest creating methods in `A` that get the values from `ComplexClass` (again to hide your implementation). If that's not suitable, then you could return the implementation by const reference: `const ComplexClass& getMember1() const { return member1; }`

Comment: Yeah, that would be the good way, but it is not a valid option to this case. As I wrote, I want to access data from member1, not to implement work on it.